# http-bio-80-exec-83] - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet'

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am pretty new to `hibernate` and I am stuck at this exception.  
I am using tomcat 7.0.42 and `mysql 5.6` and `jdk 1.7` 
`tomcat` is shutting down frequently by giving the following error log

```
2013-12-15 02:30:43,998 [http-bio-80-exec-83] - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Sat Dec 14 02:39:14 IST 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext

013-12-15 02:30:44,288 [http-bio-80-exec-83] - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@42b7983f: defining beans [org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,mcounts,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,referralSignUpRepository,balanceRepository,purchaseTrackerRepository,payments2ConsumerRepository,userRepository,merchantUserMapRepository,payments2MerchantsRepository,allPageTrackerRepository,merchantRepository,mcountsOfferRepository,nonProfitOrganisationRepository,urlLinkMapRepository,personalInfoRepository,pixelRepository,merchantOfferRepository,userRoleRepository,merchantPayments2ConsumersRepository,signUpTrackerRepository,userTransactionRepository,payments2McountsRepository,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,hibernateVendor,transactionManager,mailSender,velocityEngine,merchantOfferServiceImpl,merchantServiceImpl,userDetailServiceImpl,paymentsServiceImpl,allPageTrackerServiceImpl,nonProfitOrganisationServiceImpl,userRoleServiceImpl,userTransactionServiceImpl,mcountsOfferServiceImpl,userServiceImpl,purchaseTrackerServiceImpl,urlLinkMapServiceImpl,emailService,referralSignUpServiceImpl,signUpTrackerServiceImpl,merchantPayments2ConsumersServiceImpl,mcountsChartService,payments2ConsumerServiceImpl,personalInfoServiceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,findMerchantsController,authorizedController,profileController,externalLinksTestController,paymentsController,forgotPasswordController,merchantOfferDetailsController,thankYouPageTrackerController,insightsController,homeController,passwordResetWithoutLoginController,loginController,loginFailedController,unPaidDateRangeController,promoteMcountsController,dashBoardDataController,mcountsCampaignController,linksSharedController,signUpController,reportsController,earningsController,merchantTransfersDateRangeController,MSharePopupDisplayController,updateProfileController,dashBoardController,getMyLinkController,logoutController,mshareController,allPageTrackerController,paymentRequestController,donationRequestController,bankDetailsController,myAccountController,shareController,paidDateRangeController,changePasswordController,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#3,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#5,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#6,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#7,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#8,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#9,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#10,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#11,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#12,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#13,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#14,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#15,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#16,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#17,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Comment: Please share your configuration and if there are exceptions in the log

Comment: That's not an error log, the error happens earlier. Please post that.